# Faster Eigenvalues with lower precision goal

Tags: matrix, performance-tuning, linear-algebra

I compute all eigenvalues of a large matrix, and I decide that the speed is more important than the precision. Then the question is, can I speed up `Eigenvalues[]` by setting a lower precision goal?

For example, consider a real symmetric random $100\times 100$ matrix:

```
 In[1]:=  A = # + Transpose[#] &@RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {100, 100}];
```

and compute

```
 In[2]:=  Do[Eigenvalues[A], {10}]; // AbsoluteTiming
 Out[2]=  {0.019001,Null}
```

In real computation I may use a matrix much larger than $100\times 100$, and the computation would take much longer time than $0.019$ seconds. I want to speed up the computation. Can I set a lower precision goal, say `3`, so that `Eigenvalues[]` runs fuster? So I tried

```
 In[3]:=  Do[Eigenvalues[SetPrecision[A, 3]], {10}]; // AbsoluteTiming
 Out[3]=  {12.358707,Null}
```

The precision of the results is `3`, but the computation took `12.36` seconds. This is not what I want.

Is there a clever way to speed up `Eigenvalues[]` by setting precision goal to be `3`?

Comment: [This about lowering bitwidth](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/22650/89) might be related, though no real solution is presented there.

Answer (score 7):

*Update*: re-run the tests for 10 times each, to get better average readings. (and also corrected a coding error)

Conclusion: `Default` and `$MachinePrecision` are fastest. (hard to see any difference, did 10 times per each). So if you want fast, just use `Default`.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This [page](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v5_2/Built-inFunctions/AdvancedDocumentation/LinearAlgebra/LinearAlgebraInMathematica/MatrixComputations/EigensystemComputations/AdvancedDocumentationLinearAlgebra3.3.4.html) talks more about eigenvalue computation in Mathematica and the use of Lapack and under what condition etc....

code:

```
a = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {100, 100}];
b = c = a + Transpose[a];
r = First@Last@Reap@Do[
      b = SetPrecision[b, i];
      Sow[{i, First @ AbsoluteTiming @ Do[Eigenvalues[b], {10}]}],
      {i, 30}
      ];

Grid[Join[

  {{"Precision", "Timing (sec)"}},

  r,

  {{$MachinePrecision, b = SetPrecision[b, MachinePrecision]; 
    First @ AbsoluteTiming @ Do[Eigenvalues[b], {10}]}},

  {{Infinity, b = SetPrecision[b, Infinity]; 
    First @ AbsoluteTiming @ Do[Eigenvalues[b], {10}] }},

  {{Default, First @ AbsoluteTiming @ Do[Eigenvalues[c], {10}]}}
  ],

 Frame -> All, Spacings -> {.5, .4}]

ListLinePlot[r, Mesh -> True, MeshStyle -> Red, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {{"CPU (sec)", None}, 
 {Precision, "eigenvalue CPU vs. Precision"}}, GridLines -> Automatic, 
 GridLinesStyle -> LightGray]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I couldn't resist making a bigger plot :) http://i.stack.imgur.com/fKckc.png

Comment: Thanks for your nice codes. I got similar results using your code. Setting lower precision computes faster. The problem is, if I set `A = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {100, 100}];A = A + Transpose[A];` and compute `Eigenvalues[A];//AbsoluteTiming` without setting any precision, I got about `0.002` seconds. Once I set `SetPrecision[A, $MachinePrecision]`, which seems to change nothing, but we would get about `1.4` seconds, according to your table. In fact, setting any precision reduces the speed dramatically. Also, whether to put `SetPrecision` command inside the loop does not affect the speed.

Comment: @9527 when I do not use any `SetPrecision` on A, then CPU is just a little more than $MachinePrecision. Updated table above.

Comment: The entries in your table for `$MachinePrecision` and "Default" are not actually using machine-precision arithmetic, because `A` already has its precision set by the last time you ran `A = SetPrecision[A, i]`. You can check this using `MachineNumberQ`. To get a machine-precision version of `A`, you need to use `N[A]` instead.

Comment: Actually it turns out that `SetPrecision[#, MachinePrecision]` returns machine-precision numbers, while `SetPrecision[#, $MachinePrecision]` doesn't.

Comment: @RahulNarain good point. I did not notice this difference for MachinePrecision syntax, I'll update the result for MachinePrecision now...This shows that `Default` is fastest (which is almost the same as using MachinePrecision, but need more runs to verify, which I am doing now....)

Comment: Can anyone extend this answer for the unsolved question at: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29688/how-to-use-adaptive-precision-in-matrix-computations

Answer (score 7):

By default the computation will be done in machine precision, without precision tracking.  I believe this is the fastest method you can get without some form of packing that places multiple values in a single machine float, which I know little about.

Once you use `SetPrecision` you are engaging the arbitrary precision engine with precision tracking, which is by nature much slower than machine precision calculations.

Please see [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10624/confused-by-apparent-inconsistent-precision/10625#10625) and the posts it links to for a better explanation of *Mathematica*'s arbitrary precision engine and syntax.  Quoting from the referenced tutorial:

> Mathematica distinguishes two kinds of approximate real numbers:
>   arbitrary-precision numbers, and machine-precision numbers or machine
>   numbers. Arbitrary-precision numbers can contain any number of digits,
>   and maintain information on their precision. Machine numbers, on the
>   other hand, always contain the same number of digits, and maintain no
>   information on their precision.
>
> As discussed in more detail below, machine numbers work by making
>   direct use of the numerical capabilities of your underlying computer
>   system. As a result, computations with them can often be done more
>   quickly. They are however much less flexible than arbitrary-precision
>   numbers, and difficult numerical analysis can be needed to determine
>   whether results obtained with them are correct.

Comment: Good point. Then `SetPrecision` is different from setting a precision goal. However, it is still reasonable to expect some parameters like recursion limit or precision goal that speed up.

Comment: @9527 I believe that to *have* a precision goal the arbitrary precision engine will need to be active as without it precision is not tracked.  As for tuning parameters of the algorithm itself I don't know.

Comment: @9527 I see now that the link in Nasser's answer has information about the `Method` option of `Eigenvalues`, which I admit I've never used.  It is for the old version 5.2 however and I don't know what has changed since them.

Comment: I see. It seems the default method LAPACK is not an iterative method. So parameters like `Tolerance` or `PrecisionGoal` may not work.